# How to use BOOL in macro in IOS xCode?

Tags: xcode, macros

Hi i'm wondering how to use BOOL in macro in xCode?
like this:

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)

#ifdef IS_IPHONE5
#   define VIEW_HEIGHT_HALF 284
#else
#   define VIEW_HEIGHT_HALF 240
#endif
```

doesn't work..

so only i can code like this?

```
#define VIEW_HEIGHT_HALF (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?240:284)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Think about it: `#define` is evaluated by the *compiler*, and `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]...` is code executed at *runtime*. How should the compiler define VIEW_HEIGHT_HALF depending on a condition at program runtime?

Comment: Oh, i understand. Great thanks to Martin R!